# How to solve precision issue with tax inclusive and exclusive prices?

Tags: precision, data-modeling

User should be able to enter the full inclusive price they want to sell an item for. I store calculated exclusive price, markup, cost, and tax rate of the item. Using this I calculate the inclusive price (what our users want to see).

I can remove VAT with `exclusive = desired inclusive * 100 / (100 + tax rate)`. Getting back to inclusive price: `calculated inclusive = exclusive * (1 + (tax rate /100))`. User inputs 200 as desired inclusive selling price:

```
exclusive = 200 * 100 / (100 + 15) = 173,913043478261
```

Calculate inclusive again:

```
calculated inclusive = 173,913043478261 * (1 + (15/100)) = 200
```

I need massive precision, rounding does not reliably solve it. Exclusive/inclusive calculations don't work if I don't store a large precision on the exclusive amount. Is this the best practice? And how large does precision need to be for it to be reliable?

The alternative is store inclusive price along with tax rate. I could then calculate tax amount, round up to the 2nd decimal and subtract that when I need the exclusive. Then I only have to round once (on tax amount) and don't have to store massive precision numbers. What approach is best?

Comment: What is the real life precision of a price? Is it a whole number of cents (or whatever the smallest monetary unit is called in the currency you're using)? If not, what is the smallest fraction of a cent you must cater for?

Comment: @Bohemian thanks for the reply. The smallest fraction we need to cater for is to the second decimal. We can simply round up (or to the nearest) second decimal - but this doesn't work. We get inclusive selling prices that are off by some cents every now and then. It is hard to predict, and the issue gets compounded when you start working with larger quantities. We have tried various rounding strategies, but they all have flaws - they only work if we store large precision like the example above. If you want I can add some examples to show how the rounding doesn't work with smaller precision.

Comment: Does "second decimal" mean "0.01 of a cent"? Please provide a problematic value and calculation, showing the result you get and what the correct value is.